# 400 - Bad request while inserting record for lookup field

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am using **Microsoft Dynamics 365** and to access its database I am using **Web API** approach.

In here, I am having a field which is of lookup type and is having lookup values like below:
[image: Field information]

In here, consider its code values as below:

```
Pending: 101
Booked : 102
...
```

And what I am passing as JSON data is:

```
{
    "statuscode":"101"
}
```

I have also tried like below:

```
"statuscode":101
"statuscode":"Booked"
```

But none of them is working for me. Can someone guide me on this?

**EDIT 1: PUT Request**

> [     {       "statuscode":101,       "statecode":0   },  {
>         "statuscode":101,       "statecode":0   } ]

```
StringBuilder requestURL;
requestURL = new StringBuilder();
requestURL.Append(GenerateRequestURL(entityName));
requestURL.Append("(" + strGuID + ")");
HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonFormattedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Dictionary<string, string> returnValue;
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
returnValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
try
{
    HttpClient httpClient = SetUpCRMConnection();
    HttpRequestMessage request;
    request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, requestUrl);
    request.Content = content;
    responseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
    return GetFormattedResponse(responseMessage);
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample POST request & response ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar, I have edited my question to add sample code for request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not lookup. This is picklist a.k.a optionset.

Then statecode (status/state) & statuscode (status reason) are [conjoined twins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531157.aspx). You have to set both at the same time & most important - they should be a valid combination.

For example:

This is for Account to set it inactive.

```
// State code value
account["statecode"] = 1;
//  status reason Value
account["statuscode"] = 2;
```

Similarly, you have this combination for your entity, put it together.

Something like this:

```
entity["statecode"] = 1; //check this for "Active" in Status dropdown
entity["statuscode"] = 101; //for pending
```

Comment: This is really helpful as I was totally unaware of this concept. And actually I have such 2 fields:
- statecode   - 0 / 1
- statuscode - 101/102/103

And I have tried with all possible combination for this but still getting 400 error.

Can you tell me that how can I find that which fields are "Conjoined twins" in CRM database? OR Is there any option to check?

Comment: @PratikSoni I guess you have 2 status code attributes. One is OOB statuscode 100000000 and other one custom new_statuscode 101. OOB attributes statecode & statuscode is mandate in same order. You can refer sdk/developer guide..

Comment: not really. I have a single 'status code' only. Maybe my edited comment has confused you let me correct that again.

Comment: @PratikSoni check the variable “strGuID” value, if it contains {} then remove it. Also why the jsonformatted data is having twice?

Comment: Oh! Thanks @ArunVinoth. Your point solved my issue. My code was expecting a single value of `status code` instead of list of it. Problem solved and thank you for your help.